# How to determine Stored Procedure Error Stack Trace (mysql)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am running MySQL AWS RDS instance. I have a stored procedure that calls several other stored procedures. One of those intermittently fails.

I am trying to debug it but unfortunately the returned error indicates only the name of the parent stored procedure.

Is there a way to determine which of the child stored procedures caused the error?

Thank you, gen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to get call stack metadata from within a MySQL stored procedure.

See also my answer to [MySQL Stored Procedure logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775941/mysql-stored-procedure-logging)

This is one of several reasons I avoid MySQL stored procedures altogether. They are hard to write, hard to debug, they don't support packages or compilation, and they have poor performance and scalability.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I will use the suggested solution to include the global variable (with the latest executed procedure name) in the error handler.